# When does $X^2 + 2$ split mod prime $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields

I know that the final result will be when $p \equiv 3 \mod 8$ or when $p\equiv 1 \mod 8$. However, I do not know what to do.

For the case of $X^2 + 1$, the solution is obvious since this is just when $F_p^{\times}$ has an element of order 4, and this is when $4|p-1$. All we know here is that 2 has a 4th root.

I'm guessing the procedure is straight forward, but it remains to elude me.

Comment: This is dealt with in all number theory texts under the heading of *quadratic residues*.

Comment: Abstract duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544940/given-a-prime-q-equiv-1-3-modulo-8-show-there-exists-an-integer-x-such-t/2545001#2545001